# 12+ months old photos instagram api query

Tags: instagram

I couldn't find anything specific in instragram api's documentation, but is there any limit on how far back in time can a query go?

querying with a max timestamp of 1st of january 2013 gives me no data:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=51.5286416&lng=-0.1015987&max_timestamp=1356998400&distance=5000

whereas, the same query with the 1st of january 2014 gives me quite a few results:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=51.5286416&lng=-0.1015987&max_timestamp=1388534400&distance=5000

the limit seems to be a bit less than 12 months, i.e., I start getting results, albeit very few, around the end of june, roughly one year ago.

Comment: There are photos old 12 months?

Comment: the test location I chose was london and it seems hard to think there were no photos taken here on the 1st of january 2013 or that people only started using instagram after july 2013